# I am not sure how to exclude one line among the list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to exclude the last line shows "cwd=/" alone from the following list. Rest I want to display

```
   1111 cwd=/path/to/file
   1139 cwd=/path/to/file
   1330 cwd=/path/to/file
   1330 cwd=/path/to/file
   2739 cwd=/path/to/file
   3273 cwd=/path/to/file
   9573 cwd=/path/to/file
   9981 cwd=/
```

What I meant once exluding the last line, I want result as follows:

```
   1111 cwd=/path/to/file
   1139 cwd=/path/to/file
   1330 cwd=/path/to/file
   1330 cwd=/path/to/file
   2739 cwd=/path/to/file
   3273 cwd=/path/to/file
   9573 cwd=/path/to/file
```

Any idea how to do that with grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
sed '$d' filename
```

This is only applicable for removing the last line only..

Answer (score 0):

Require a character after the false match.

```
grep 'cwd=/.'
```

Comment: wow, thank you :) can you explain how this is working? that dot "." means space after trailing slash?

Comment: A `.` in a regex matches any character.